# How are the function/methods defined inside a class Based Views CBV are called?

Tags: python, oop, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-class-based-views

I have been learning the Django framework for 3-4 months but there is 1 thing that bugs me the most and I am unable to find a satisfactory answer yet.When we define the functions/methods inside a Class based views, do they get called automatically when some object is created? Like we use

```
@action(detail=False)
    def recent_users(self, request):
        recent_users = User.objects.all().order_by('-last_login')

        page = self.paginate_queryset(recent_users)
        if page is not None:
            serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
            return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)

        serializer = self.get_serializer(recent_users, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

How this method will be executed? DO we have to make an object and call like obj.method?

And how those  `get() get_queryset()` methods work given with the Class Based Views?? How do they process the data from models?

and one last question would be the mixture of these both.

***Can I create a new method inside a ClassBasedView? If yes, How do I execute it ?*** Say in return and render data inside a template ?

Please do not provide any link. I just want to know in simple English terms. If anybody knows, it'll be very helpful.

Comment: Did you checked what is `view`, why/how it is used and how it is called/executed ?

Comment: I am talking about class based views. How ```get()``` method is called? Does ti get called on its own>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When referencing a class based view in the `path` (`url` prior to 2.X) function we call the [`as_view` class method](https://github.com/django/django/blob/2.2.4/django/views/generic/base.py#L49). Looking at the source code will show that this essentially defines a function view that calls a class based view's `dispatch` method.

What this means is that the entry point in a class based view is the `dispatch` method. All other methods are called somewhere down the line from `dispatch`. The methods immediately called by dispatch are all going to be [named according to HTTP methods](https://github.com/django/django/blob/2.2.4/django/views/generic/base.py#L94) (E.G. `get`, `post`, `delete`).

This is the typical path for a view inheriting from `TemplateView`.

1. `as_view` returns a function that calls `dispatch`.
2. `dispatch` calls `get` or, if `request.method` isn't `GET`, the `http_method_not_allowed` method.
3. `get` calls `get_context_data` and passes that as an argument to `render_to_response`.
4. `render_to_response` calls `get_template_names` and passes that as an argument to `TemplateResponse`.

You can define any method you want on your class based view, but it won't be called unless you call it somewhere that is already being called.

One common modification is to add something to `get_context_data`.

```py
   def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
       kwargs.setdefault('recent_users', self.recent_users())
       return super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

   def recent_users(self):
       # self.request is accessible here.
       ...
```

https://ccbv.co.uk/ is a helpful resource for writing class based views. I reference that site all the time while I'm writing class based views.